# How to dynamically move a polygon in map canvas?

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to dynamically move a polygon on QGIS map canvas with a python script. The polygon coordinates are updated every n seconds in txt file by an outside application. I tried the following code:

```
def main():
    path_coordinates='path_to_polygon_coordinates.txt'
    polygon_coordinates=coords_polygon(path_coordinates) #function that reads coordinates in txt file and return them in a list
    polygon=QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([polygon_coordinates])

    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:2154&field=id:int(2)',    'Layer 1'   , "memory")
    mapregistry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(polygon)
    vpr = vlayer.dataProvider()
    vpr.addFeatures([feature])
    vlayer.updateExtents()

    for k in range(99):
        actualize_position(path_coordinates,vlayer)

def actualize_position(path_coordinates,vlayer):
    polygon_coordinates=coords_polygon(path_coordinates)
    polygon=QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([polygon_coordinates])
    feat_id=1
    vlayer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({feat_id:polygon})
    vlayer.updateExtents()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The problem I get while running the script is that QGIS freezes until the script is finished. What I would like to get is to be able to see the polygon moving on the map canvas.